# Create a menu, how many ways

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I have an assignment and just wanted to verify if my answer is correct.
 
Possibilities:
 
main courses: cheeseburger, fish
side dishes: lentils, fries
desserts: chocolate cake, vanilla ice, fruit salad

How many ways are there for a guest to create a menu. You can choose 1 dish of the main courses, 3 of the side dishes, 2 of the desserts.

My solution would be this: 
$$
{2 \choose 1} \cdot \frac{5!}{2!} \cdot {3 \choose 2} = 360
$$

Comment: You only seem to have listed 2 side dishes, not 5.

Comment: I don;t get it ... you can have 3 side dishes but only 2 to choose from ??  The $5$ in your formula suggests you actually have 5 to choose from, is that right?  But then why not $5 \choose 2$? Why use a different formula for the side dishes than for main dish and dessert?

Comment: Also assuming there ar 5 side dishes to choose from, why $\frac{5!}{2!}$ instead of ${5\choose2}$?

Comment: I used the formula n+k-1 choose k  because i can choose 3 side dishes but have just 2 of them. Oh i see now it should had been 4 choose 2 right?

Comment: @Jag  So you really have just 2 side dishes?!  But who on earth would pick 3 side dishes of fries?   Well, I suppose someone could ... but realistically speaking, wouldn't it make more sense to say that they could pick *up to* 3 side dishes, with possible repeats?  In fact, the same could be said for the dessert ... and someone may even choose to not have a main dish I suppose.  So now you have many more options.

Comment: @Bram Yes i just have 2 side dishes. I think not to choose is not an option.

Comment: I guess my answer is right hahaha

Comment: @Jag OK ... so that means repeats ... so then why not have repeats for dessert? If I can have 3 side dishes of fries, then why not have 2 dishes of vanilla ice? Cheese burger, 3 fries, and 2 vanilla ice: that should sustain me for the day to come :)

Comment: @Canardini I'm as baffled as you are :) LOL

Comment: exactly, who does not want two slices of chocolate cake !

Comment: Hey @Jag ... I hope you don't take offense at our banter. It's certainly not directed at you, but just at the absurdity of this question  (or at least its ambiguity and unrealistic nature if you are indeed *forced* to have 3 side dishes with only 2 to choose from). So, here's my advice:  if this is your HW, point out these ambiguities and absurdities in the question, and provide separate answers for the different constraints you can take. Any teacher worth their salt will give you bonus points!

Comment: @Bram Haha no, i'm just glad that you guys could help there. I know, it also confused me, i will ask my lecturer about the answer. But i think Canardini's answer was right.

Comment: @Jag OK, good. And yes, please ask your Lecturer, and please edit your post when you find out; I'm really curious now what was really meant. I laughed my ass off when I saw Canardini's answer, but it may yet turn out to be correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

-Two choices for the main course : burger or fish.

-$4$ choices for the side dish : Either you pick no fries, one fries, two fries or three fries, the rest is completed by lentils.

-${3 \choose 2}$ of desserts.

The result is $$2*4*{3 \choose 2}$$

Comment: LOL! A creative solution to the side dish issue! :) Though I pity the person who doesn't like fries: 3 lentil dishes for you!

Comment: Fries all day everyday haha

Comment: I just noticed my mistake now, thank you!